# How to show merge data from two sharepoint list and show it in excel

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have two SharePoint lists A and B which have 2 same columns namely "Task" and "Details". I want to merge the data from both list and display it in excel sheet which show current data every time it is opened. I know how to show data of one list in excel and I am familiar with the concept of linked data source to merge data of both list and show in aspx page using sharepoint designer but not sure how to display it in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options but the one I know it is using SharePoint REST API.

All you need is to create 2 queries and later use "Append" or "Merge" to get results combine, here it is an example: you have two lists named **ListA** and **ListB**, you query each into Excel like using a REST API call, something similar like the following:

For the first sheet:

```
http://domain-name/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=Title,Task,Details
```

And the second sheet:

```
http://domain-name/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListB')/items?$select=Title,Task,Details
```

[image]

Once you have the data sources (QUERY1 and QUERY2) into your Excel, you can go to the Merge or Append, and combine both queries into a new data:

[image]

[image]

This is an example of an APPEND:

[image]

And this is an example of a MERGE:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr Sushi. for the detailed explanation. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i am facing a problem with this approach in excel online. I have put connection to be refreshed every time this file is opened but when ever i try to open the excel with merged data which i uplaoded on sharepoint it gives me error "External data refresh Failed". for all the 3 queries i used (say Query1, Query2, and Append1). Do you have any quess why this might be happening? The problem doesn't come if I download the excel file and refresh the data stored loacaly

Comment: Please go throuh this link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511069/getting-error-external-data-refresh-failed-while-refreshing-excel-odata-querie