# Getting error "External data refresh failed" while refreshing excel odata queries in excel file uploaded on sharepoint online

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online

I have created 2 odata queries in excel which fetch data from 2 sharepoint lists. Then I appended the 2 queries to append the data from both list into one. Now i have three queries, Query 1 fro list 1, Query 2 for list 2, and Query append for appended data. I went to connection settings and checked the option to refresh my queries every time the excel file is opened so that I have latest data from my lists.
[Query Properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7kLn.jpg).
I saved the file and uplaoded on sharepoint library. Now whenever i open the file from sharepoint in excel online I get an error "External data refresh failed".[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zes00.jpg).
The data doesnt get refreshed if i press ok.

Strangely this problem does not comes if I download the excel file and open it locally and refresh the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a connection in the Secure Store and tie the credentials to later be used by your Excel spreadsheet.

Once you supply the user account and password in the Secure Store, you will need to get back to your Excel spreadsheet and change the authentication settings to match the one from the Secure Store, enter it on the Application ID.